# How to measure SQL query cost to appease requirements of SQL Governor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On a shared hosting provider I am getting an error like:

> The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (1660) exceeds the configured threshold of 1500. Contact the system administrator.

I understand that this is because the SQL Server 2008 instance being used has SQL Governor enabled, and consequently I need to reduce the cost of my query.

I'd like to repro this condition on my dev machine.  However resource governor is only available in the enterprise edition of MSSQL2008 (which I don't have) so I cannot enable it locally.

Can I measure a query locally?  What are the units of this limit (1500)?

**EDIT** To be clear, I *have* MSSQL on my machine already, but the version doesn't support SQL Governor (you need the Enterprise version for that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a copy of SQL Developer Edition.  It's dirt cheap and has all the features of full blown enterprise.  With our corporate license we got a license for like $30.

If you don't want to buy it you can typically download a 60 day (or longer) trial and at least use it long enough to troubleshoot your situation.

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx

The other problem however is that you'd also have to mimic the load of the hosting server and the hardware to get an accurate picture of it's estimated cost vs yours.  That could get complex.

The second part of your question:  The [unit of measure for the cost is a time measurement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190419.aspx) (seconds).  If the server estimates that it will take longer than the max to execute then it's a no-go.

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear enough -- I have a version already (Standard Edition, by the looks of it) in which SQL Governor cannot be enabled.  I guess it's a feature for hosting providers, and they have to pay for the hefty enterprise edition.  So I'm looking for a way to enable this feature on my lesser version of MSSQL.

Comment: No, I understood but if you wanted to play with that actual feature it's just a "trial" download away.  I also updated my answer with the second half of your question.

Comment: @Drew Noakes, like lazyDBA said, for development you should be using SQL Developer Edition, not Standard edition.  Developer will get you the enterprise features for local development and testing.

Comment: @lazyDBA, if the cost measurement really is seconds, then 1500 is a huge threshold.  Sounds more like milliseconds, in which case it's relatively small but should be livable for most applications.

Comment: Ah ok, my mistake.  The error message I received said I needed Enterprise Edition.  Makes sense that it's available to developers too.  Thanks.  Wow, it does seem to be in seconds.  There's no way my query took that long, but looking at the generated SQL (I'm using EF4) I can see why it might get the estimate wrong.  It took me 1500 seconds just to work out what it was doing.  Some reworking on the high-level LINQ stuff seems to have brough the cost down considerably and made my host's system happier.  If I hit this issue again, I'll kick off a trial period of the dev version.  Cheers!

Comment: Sam Neff, I got the time measurement from books online (see link).  I was surprised as well.  They list 121 (2 min) in the examples for most hosted solutions.  1500 IS a pretty big threshold, nearly half an hour.

Comment: EF can create some pretty intense queries.  And people complained about LINQ to SQL.  Frankly, from what I've seen of some of the code-first approaches they aren't too impressive either.